# Transaction Propagation feature in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, spring-transactions

In our project we need to use `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` for `PlatformTransactionManager` within **Hazelcast** transaction, but unfortunately there is no support for "nested" transactions in *Hazelcast*.

The question is how we can have this with **Hazelcast** internal API or maybe some workaround?

Currently we use pretty ugly solution with new `Thread` like below:

```
    //We have existing Hazelcast transaction here   
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
           //within separate Thread we will have new Hazelcast transaction context here.
        });
    t.start();
    //wait here while Thread will complete execution
    t.join();
```

Such approach works, but maybe there is another way which would be more acceptable?

Comment: Also there is an [issue #13540](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/13540) to implement this in Hazelcast, but when this will be done is incomprehensible.

Comment: anyone who needs this feature, it will be great if you will be able to upvote github issue because guys from Hazelcast promised to implement it in case of community will have interest